# Should I mention my Canadian visa refusal( Ban) in my UK visa application for study permit?

Tags: uk, canada, visa-refusals, applications, study

Actually I ban from Canada country. As per the email they said you have missrepresentation on your document. But its not my fault. My consultant made a mistake and now I am suffering it , but nothing was stamped in my passport. Howerver, now i want to apply in UK for study permit. What is the correct path. Could you please help me ?

First of all can i apply ? Is I am eligible to apply

Thanks.[image]

Comment: The correct path is to truthfully answer all questions on the application form. If you lie, that will be misrepresentation that is unambiguously your fault.

Comment: I will add three other uncomfortable bits: first, you are responsible for what a "consultant" does in your name; second, stamps in your passport don't matter, as a ban doesn't attach to the passport, it attaches to _you_ as an individual; and third, the UK and Canada share immigration data and information, so the UK will know of your Canada ban. If you don't answer truthfully, UKVI will have you for deception and you'll be banned from the UK as well.

Comment: Please do not say "My consultant made a mistake". A 'mistake' is something that you do accidentally. Your consultant deliberately attached fraudulent documents to your application. That is not a 'mistake'.

Comment: Not sure what further correspondence you received, but the part of the letter you included does not say you have been banned from Canada, but that you could be under certain conditions. Given that page only, you have had a visa denied, you haven’t been banned. Even if that is the case, you should most definitely make sure that any further applications for studies in Canada or the UK are 100% truthful and honest.

Comment: And please let me know, in this letter are you sure that its  say that I am banned from Canada for 5 years. Cause my consultant told me that a banned from Canada and USA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you apply? Yes.

If the application form asks about your previous immigration history, you must answer truthfully. Should you be tempted to risk answering otherwise, you should be aware that Canada shares biometric information with the United States, Australia, New Zealand and the United Kingdom.

https://www.cicnews.com/2018/07/canadas-new-biometrics-rules-start-july-31-heres-what-you-need-to-know-0710947.html

Comment: So, if I tell truthfully whatever they ask so it means they can granted my study permit for UK.

Comment: @Pankaj Sehgal No. It means your Canada refusal/ban does not make you ineligible to apply for a UK visa. The UK will almost certainly know about it. If you tell the truth, you MAY get your visa, providing you meet all the eligibility criteria. If you lie, you definitely won’t. If you don’t understand whether you actually have a ban or not, then I suggest it would be better not to apply until you do, and that you don’t just rely on what a ‘consultant’ is telling you (especially if you’re paying them) unless they are a qualified Immigration lawyer.

Comment: As per you what do you think what does it mean as per letter !!! Please let me know !!!